# .NET6/.NetCore HttpClient does not honor no_proxy settings on Linux for subdomains

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, proxy, httpclient

We're running multiple ASPNETCore servers (on Linux) communicating with each other on a corporate network. The http_proxy is set as well as the no_proxy env variable. When one server calls another via this setup we receive 504 Gateway error, which implies that the client tries to communicate to the other intranet server via the proxy gateway.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the format how we specify subdomains in no_proxy does matter. We have addresses for servers like server1.subd.local, server2.subd.local, etc.
We originally specified no_proxy as "subd.local" so that all servers within the subdomain are excluded from the proxy. This setup is ok for linux (i.e. you can curl the servers from bash prompt), but not ok for HttpClient. You have to add a leading dot so the no_proxy should become ".subd.local".